# substitute strlen with sizeof for c-string

Tags: c++, c, arrays, cstring

I want to use mbstowcs_s method but without iostream header. Therefore I cannot use strlen to predict the size of my buffer. The following method has to simply change c-string to wide c-string and return it:

```
char* changeToWide(char* value)
{
   wchar_t* vOut = new wchar_t[strlen(value)+1];
   mbstowcs_s(NULL,vOut,strlen(val)+1,val,strlen(val));
   return vOut;
}
```

As soon as i change it to

```
char* changeToWide(char* value)
{
   wchar_t* vOut = new wchar_t[sizeof(value)];
   mbstowcs_s(NULL,vOut,sizeof(value),val,sizeof(value)-1);
   return vOut;
}
```

I get wrong results (values are not the same in both arrays). What is the best way to work it out?
I am also open for other ideas how to make that conversion without using strings but pure arrays

Comment: `strlen` lives in the `string.h` header. Either use that, or write your own `strlen`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use string.h . Btw is it possible to perform such a conversion without any header? Just pure c

Comment: Yes, as I said, write your own `strlen` function.

Comment: Writing your own `strlen` is trivial: `size_t strlen(char * s){ size_t ret = 0; while(*s++) ret++; return ret; }`

Comment: I meant to convert char* to wchar_t without any header, since not I need stdlib.h to use mbstowcs_s

Comment: Why can't you use `string.h`?

Comment: The function returning `char *` type is a mistake, right? I don't think you'd like an implicit typecast there...

Comment: *Why* can't you use `<string.h>`? Without knowing the reason for that seemingly arbitrary restriction, we can't determine what the best workaround might be.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: There is no implicit conversion from `wchar_t*` to `char*`; it would simply fail to compile (or *possibly* compile with a warning).

Answer (score 3):

Given a char* or const char* you cannot use sizeof() to get the size of the string being pointed by your char* variable. In this case, sizeof() will return you the number of bytes a pointer uses in memory (commonly 4 bytes in 32-bit architectures and 8 bytes in 64-bit architectures).

If you have an array of characters defined as array, you can use sizeof:

```
char text[] = "test";
auto size = sizeof(text); //will return you 5 because it includes the '\0' character.
```

But if you have something like this:

```
char text[] = "test";
const char* ptext = text;
auto size2 = sizeof(ptext); //will return you probably 4 or 8 depending on the architecture you are working on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am an expert on this matter, but `char` to `wchar_t` conversion being made is seemingly nothing but using a wider space for the exact same bytes, in other words, prefixing each `char` with some set of zeroes.

I don't know C++ either, just C, but I can derive what it probably would look like in C++ by looking at your code, so here it goes:

```
wchar_t * changeToWide( char* value )
{
    //counts the length of the value-array including the 0
    int i = 0;
    while ( value[i] != '\0' ) i++;

    //allocates enough much memory
    wchar_t * vOut = new wchar_t[i];

    //assigns values including the 0
    i = 0;
    while ( ( vOut[i] = 0 | value[i] ) != '\0' ) i++;

    return vOut;
}
```

`0 |` part looks truly obsolete to me, but I felt like including it, don't really know why...